# How to use Power Query to create pivot tables with non-numerical values

Tags: microsoft-excel, powerpivot, power-query

The data is transformed into an Excel table and loaded into Power Query. It looks like this:

(I don't understand why the table doesn't work. After a few searches I realize that the site does not support table markdown)

`| Name          | ID            |Analyst  |
|Name1          | 1000001       | Tony    |
|Name2          | 1000002       | Tony    |
|Name3          | 1000045       | Adam    |
|Name4          | 1000009       | Adam    |
|Name5          | 1000321       | Jimmy   |
|Name6          | 1000040       | Adam    |
|Name7          | 1000005       | Jimmy   |`

`ID` is unique.

I'd like to create a pivot table into this form:

`Tony   1000001
       1000002
Adam   1000009
       1000040
       1000045
Jimmy  1000005
       1000321`

I do not need to keep the `Name` field, and it's not necessary to sort the table by Analyst or by Spot id. I'm looking forward to use a few lines of M code to do this, but found nothing suitable for my cause.

BTW please also let me know if it's doable in Power Pivot with DAX. I know how to do this in VBA, quite trivial, but I need to teach the non-programmers how to do this with DAX/M, and it's embarrassing as I don't them them either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a Pivot Table to create that output, either via the Excel Data Model/Power Pivot or directly from an Excel Table output by your Power Query.

Just add the Analyst and then ID columns to the **Rows** well in the **PivotTable Fields** pane and you will get the output you are after.  If you want to output as 2 columns, set the PivotTable's **Report Layout** = Tabular Form.

I dont think any DAX or M code is needed.

Comment: Thanks! Not sure how come I didn't think about that...